# What does cv2.cornerHarris return?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have been reading about `cornerHarris` in OpenCV. I read through the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html) but I am not sure what does this function return.

While reading through the [examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html), there is a statement written as:

```
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)

img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

I just cannot understand the second statement above, may be because I do not understand, what is `cornerHarris` actually returning.

I do sense, that there is some kind of threshold being applied, but I cannot explain.

Answer (score 5):

I just checked the example page you linked:

> Threshold for an optimal value, it may vary depending on the image. img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]

This is the documentation page I was actually looking for:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=cornerharris#cornerharris

> Corners in the image can be found as the local maxima of this response
>   map.

The cv2.cornerHarris detector returns the corners that were found. As usual this method does not return a list of corners that were found. Instead, it returns an 2d-array - same size as the input - with probabilities. Each position inside this array holds the confidence in this pixel being a corner  (to be precise it is not the single pixel, that is predicted to be a corner. It is the neighbourhood that is centered at this coordinates)

So most likely cv2.cornerHarris returns a value for confidence in it's own prediction. And with 
`dst>0.01*dst.max()` 
the code filters corners that are only "low-confidence-corners". Any corner that is detected will just be marked as a corner if the confidence is higher than 1% of the highest confidence.

Answer (score 0):

```
dst = cv2.cornerHarris(gray,2,3,0.04)
```

**dst** is resultant 2D probability array with the same shape as of input image.

```
img[dst>0.01*dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

The above code is marely a post-processing technique, where "low-confidence-corners" are filtered out.

or to interpret differently:

**Filter in** *those probabilities whose confidence is more than 1% of the max. probability in the resultant 2D probability array*

From the [examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_features_harris/py_features_harris.html) documentation. If the image is less complex as given below, Even the below code will work fine:

```
img[dst == dst.max()]=[0,0,255]
```

[image: Harris corner]

For more clarity, plot the resultant 2D probability array using matplotlib:

```
def display(img, mapp='gray'):
    plt.imshow(img, cmap=mapp)
    plt.show()
```